# Wordpress no me esta utilizando la pagina page.php

Tags: html5, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Un saludo, necesito utilizar la pagina page.php pero siempre se carga es la index.php y no se por que se presenta esto, ya que la jerarquía de wordpress debe mostrar siempre a page.php primero que el index.php obviamente las dos paginas ya están creadas, quisiera su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Desde dónde la quieres utilizar?

`page.php` es el template default de las páginas, intenta ponerte otro template a la página que creaste.

Si estás usando `get_template_part()` prueba llamando a page directamente `get_template_part('page')`

Comment: Lo unico que pasa es que esta page.php no se esta cargando como principal, la que se esta cargando es el index.php y no entiendo por que, ya que asi funciona la gerarquia de wordpress